# Configure Always On to use secondary site as DR

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2017, standard-edition

I have two SQL Server 2017 Standard Edition clusters, each in a different datacenter, only a pair of servers each.

I was able to configure and test the Windows Cluster, Quorum for it, AG, including failing over from primary to secondary, and created one listener for each.

How do you think I can replicate to second DC?

I can't upgrade to SQL Server Enterprise to use Distributed AG.

Answer (score 4):

Standard Edition availability groups are limited to one replica, which is clearly stated in  the documentation at [Basic Always On availability groups for a single database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/basic-availability-groups-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver15#limitations).  So if you need to maintain a another copy, you'll need to use a different option.

Some possibilities are:

- Log shipping
- Replicate the entire server at the virtual server's host layer with something like Zerto
- Replicate the storage at the storage layer
- Replicate the database files with a third party product that performs host-level file replication (e.g., Carbonite Double-Take).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above post, you can also setup Transactional Replication (SQL Server feature) from Primary server at datacenter 1 to Primary server at datacenter 2

It is a bit cumbersome to configure and maintain, but still a viable option

Research shows that it should be possible to setup Transactional Replication from one AG Listener to another

[How to set up a transactional replication to an Always On Availability Group (AG) with two replicas through connecting to the AG Listener](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/215302/how-to-set-up-a-transactional-replication-to-an-always-on-availability-group-ag)